# Mask Image, create rectangle from multiple gradients

Tags: css, linear-gradients, radial-gradients, css-mask

I have a radial gradient that used as a `mask-image` "fades" an image in to the `background-color` *behind* the image.

```
mask-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
```

How do I get the same effect with an evenly rectangular gradient on all four sides?

I know you can combine gradients and my most current attempt does not seem to have any effect:

```
img
{
 mask-image: 
  linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%),
  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%),
  linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%),
  linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick with multiple mask is to control the size/position so that each one will apply to a region of your element:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1003/300/300);
  -webkit-mask: 
     linear-gradient(to top,    transparent,#fff) top   /100% 20%,
     linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent,#fff) bottom/100% 20%,
     linear-gradient(to left  , transparent,#fff) left  /20% 100%,
     linear-gradient(to right , transparent,#fff) right /20% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  mask: 
     linear-gradient(to top,    transparent,#fff) top   /100% 20%,
     linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent,#fff) bottom/100% 20%,
     linear-gradient(to left  , transparent,#fff) left  /20% 100%,
     linear-gradient(to right , transparent,#fff) right /20% 100%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

[image: CSS multiple mask to create blurry hole]

Or like this:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1003/300/300);
  -webkit-mask: 
    linear-gradient(to top,  transparent 10%, #fff 15% 90%, transparent 95%),
    linear-gradient(to left, transparent 10%, #fff 15% 90%, transparent 95%);
  -webkit-mask-size:110% 110%;
  -webkit-mask-position:center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-composite: source-in;
  
  
  mask: 
    linear-gradient(to top,  transparent 10%, #fff 15% 90%, transparent 95%),
    linear-gradient(to left, transparent 10%, #fff 15% 90%, transparent 95%);
  mask-size: 110% 110%;
  mask-position: center;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask-composite: intersect;
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

[image: Multiple CSS mask for blurry edge]

Related: [How to make a rectangular transparency gradient CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59663565/8620333)

Comment: The first one is an inverse of what I'm trying to accomplish so I'll try switching the positioning. I'm not sure what is going on with the second set. I test in Waterfox first/by default.

Comment: @John I created both variant, the second one is the opposite of the first one. they should work fine in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Fantastic! The second one is what I'm interested in. Because I'm absolutely certain that I'll be using `mask` a *lot* in the future I've started to record what works. I even somehow generated a cross and your first one would work to censor or perhaps some game where guessing is a key component. Great stuff, thank you!

Comment: @John I already provided some answers using mask trick if you are intrested ;) https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a8620333%20mask

Comment: Lol awesome! I'll edit your answer here to reflect what I was trying to do (since I didn't provide a screenshot or anything). Thank you again! :-)

Comment: @John note that for the mask-composite you need intersect when using `mask-composite` and source-in when using `-webkit-mask-composite`

Comment: There *had* to be something messy. ︎ I have it working save a small bug in my platform's preprocessor. I was actually dealing with that and was about to comment. ︀