# Blur a single side of an image

Tags: html, css, css-filters, css-mask

How can I blur one side of an image to create a nice transition from the image to a background?

I was able to do it with this little hack:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image-blurred {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/9');
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    filter: blur(15px);
    position: relative;
}

.frontimage {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
    from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="image-blurred"></div>
<div class="frontimage"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/9"></div>
</div>
```

but `-webkit-mask-image` is not a reliable option.

Is there any other ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correctly write the mask and it's reliable https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks (only IE is not supported which is not a surprise)

You can also simplify your code like below:

```css
.frontimage img {
  filter: blur(15px);
}
.frontimage {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-bottom:50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frontimage::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/9');
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:50px;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, transparent);
          mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="frontimage">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/9">
</div>
```

Related question to get a different effect: [Mask Image, create rectangle from multiple gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60574155/8620333)